# How can do a query in Tfs API, get all workitem if they doesn't contains field more value than list

Tags: tfs

I want to do a Query in TFSAPi to select all workitems that the 'configuration' field doesn't contains more value than configurationList

```
var configurationList=["aa","bb,"cc"];
select * from workitems where configuration ??? configurationList

in case: workitem.configuration = "aa","bb,"dd" => will not return
in case: workitem.configuration = "aa","bb" => return
in case: workitem.configuration = "aa","bb","cc", "dd => will not return
in case: workitem.configuration = "bb" =>  return
```

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql

Comment: It's difficult to match all the conditions, however you can try do the query separately with each condition restricted.